# Confusion with subject of "остаться"

Tags: грамматика

A Russian song has the two lines
Нашей любви осталась минутка and 
Нашей любви зачем не осталось?

I think the subject of the first line is минутка (feminine). What is the subject of the second line? Presumably it is neuter because of осталось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an instance of ***Genitive negative*** associated in particular with verbs of existence/habitation/occurrence such as **быть**, **существовать**, **находиться**, **проживать**, **происходить**, **проявляться**, **обнаруживаться**, **возникать** to name a few, and **остаться** as well, which turns the sentence into an impersonal one.

All these verbs are intransitive (the reflexive obviously are).

Some linguists label it ***Genitive of the subject*** [(paragraph 6.1.1. Генитив субъекта)](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5#6_1).

Examples

> Катастрофы *не произошло*
>   Сомнений *не возникло*
>   Отклонений *не наблюдалось*
>   Ответа *не пришло*

Comment: So, if the second sentence was positive, would it be зачем наша любовь осталась? and the subject would be наша любовь

Comment: @Bob Daley exactly

Answer (score 1):

**Остаться** can be used in a number of ways. The first one is like a usual intransitive verb, and that's your first example:

> Нашей любви осталась минутка. — *[Just] a minute of our love is left*.

You are right, here **минутка** or more specifically **минутка нашей любви** is the subject.

But in your second example, *осталось* is used as an impersonal verb. It has the neuter-gender form, but there is no neuter gender nouns around, that is because the implied subject is *оно* 'it' which is always omitted before the Russian impersonal verbs. The best way to look at the structure of this sentence this way:

> Нашей любви зачем не осталось? – Why [isn't] [there] [any] of our love left?

*Нашей любви* is in the genitive case because of the negative verb, ***не*** осталось, just the same way as we say *Есть деньги?* (nominative case), but *Нет денег?* (genitive case).